# How to restrict PHP file access using .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My base folder contains one "index.php" file and "app" folder and the app folder contains some php files and i don't want to direct access these php files inside app folder using browser.

Comment: The rule itself looks fine, but why those conditions? They actually _allow_ access to the other php files!

Comment: if i remove the conditions , then the css and js inside my app folder was not loading in the browser

Comment: Ah, so you have more complex requirements. Then you need more specific conditions that only prevent access to php files, but not to _all_ existing files as you coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As worked out in the comments to your question your requirements are actually a little more complex than what you wrote in your question.

I guess this is what you are actually looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite requests to `index.php` when the file name in the request ends in the `.php` file name extension.

Comment: ok it works for me and i had another problem , when i access some file in app folder then the css and js file location alters relative to that file instead of index.php . So it shows page without css and js . how to solve it ?

Comment: I don't see how this can happen if it is always the same script that is called (index.php). From there the paths to the assets are static, clear and defined. I do not see an issue there. You could start using absolute paths in your references to the assets, but that is bad style, since it reduces portability of your code.

Comment: will this code work for all sub folders ?. that is, if request made to any php file in sub folders will redirect to index.php file ?

Comment: It will work for all subfolders of the one where this `.htaccess` style file is placed and interpreted in, since it does not care for folders. It only checks if the requested path ends in the file name extension `.php`.

Comment: A general remark, please do not get that wrong: I have the impression that you do not really understand how that stuff works. But it is _very_ dangerous if you use things you do not understand and rely on them. I suggest you start reading the documentation of apaches rewriting module to learn how things really work: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: if i access different php file other than index.php then the browser set that other php file as base file and search for css and js , so the css and js were not loading .

Comment: Em, that description is a bit off, but anyway: certainly you may have to change your asset references if you suddenly start your execution in another directory than before (by using the above rewriting logic). Nothing you can do against that. You could try to create some wild rewriting logic for those assets based on the referrer or something, but that is a horrible approach. All asset paths should always be defined relative to your router script (index.php).